# Z3 Setting Random Seed using C-API

Tags: z3

In the Z3 options we get -

```
Search heuristics:
  -rd:num     random case-split frequency (default: 2).
  -rs:num     random seed.
```

I am wondering, if there is an C API to set the random seed?

I use the following API to set the timeout.
Is there anything similar for random seed?

```
params = Z3_mk_params(ctx);         
Z3_params_set_uint(ctx, params, Z3_mk_string_symbol(ctx, ":timeout"),  timeout);            
Z3_solver_set_params(ctx, solver, params);
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the parameter is `:random-seed`. The value is also a `unsigned int`.

That being said, the next Z3 version (v4.3.2) will have much better support for setting parameters. The improvements are already available in the `unstable` (work-in-progress) branch at http://z3.codeplex.com.

Comment: Just to clarify, does random-seed guarantee me that I will get the same model each time I run z3? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. Z3 is supposed to be deterministic. Given a set of input parameters and a platform (e.g., Linux), Z3 should produce always the same result. If this is not the case, then it is a bug in Z3, and it should be fixed. We fixed bugs like that in the past.